# Raven DB: How to create "UniqueVisitorCount by date" index

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

I have an application to track the page visits for a website.
Here's my model:

```cs
public class VisitSession {
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public string UniqueVisitorId { get; set; }
    public IList<PageVisit> PageVisits { get; set; }
}
```

When a visitor go to the website, a visit session starts. One visit session has many page visits. The tracker will write a UniqueVisitorId (GUID) cookie when the first time a visitor go to the website. So we are able to know if a visitor is returning visitor.

Now, I want to know how many **unique visitors** visited the website in a date range. That is, I want to display a table in our webpage like this;

```
Date        | Unique Visitors Count
------------+-----------------------
2012-05-01  | 100
2012-05-02  | 1000
2012-05-03  | 120
```

I want to create an index to do this in RavenDB. But I don't know how to write the Map/Reduce query. I though it can be like this:

```cs
public class UniqueVisitor_ByDate : AbstractIndexCreationTask<VisitSession, UniqueVisitorByDate>
{
    public UniqueVisitor_ByDate()
    {
        Map = sessions => from s in sessions
                            select new
                            {
                                s.StartTime.Date,
                                s.UniqueVisitorId
                            };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Date into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Date = g.Key,
                                UniqueVisitorCount = g.Distinct()
                            };
    }
}
```

But it's not working. In Ayende's e-book, I know that the result of Map function should be same as the result of Reduce function. So how can I write the correct map/reduce functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This index should do what you want:

```
public class UniqueVisitor_ByDate : AbstractIndexCreationTask<VisitSession, UniqueVisitorByDate>
{
    public UniqueVisitor_ByDate()
    {
        Map = sessions => 
            from s in sessions
            select new {
                s.StartTime.Date,
                s.UniqueVisitorId,
                Count = 1,
            };

        Reduce = results =>
            from result in results
            group result by result.Date
            into g
            select new UniqueVisitorByDate {
                Date = g.Key,
                Count = g.Select(x => x.UniqueVisitorId).Distinct().Count(),
                UniqueVisitorId = g.FirstOrDefault().UniqueVisitorId,
            };
    }
}
```

Note that it requires the extra 'UniqueVisitorId' property in the 'reduce' and the 'count' property in the map, but you can just ignore those.

Comment: But adding "UniqueVisitorId" to UniqueVisitorByDate class looks strange, is there a better solution?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  You could change the name of the property to something like 'TempId_DO_NOT_USE' to indicate that it shouldn't be used in your application.

Comment: @DylanLin `UniqueVisitorId` has to be part of `UniqueVisitorByDate` because Map and Reduce must produce objects of the same shape.

Comment: But still made the UniqueVisitorByDate class not elegant :(

Comment: Elegance or pragmatism... in this case, as that class is only used to display the results and isn't part of your domain or business logic I think it's a small price to pay for an index that actually works! :-)

Comment: Hi, I found that this will not work. No error, but calculated incorrect result. Code with sample data: Code with sample data can be found here: https://gist.github.com/2702071

Comment: That code doesn't really match your question - this code uses a multi map, so isn't the same thing.

Comment: @DylanLin Actually, if you change your Reduce to set `UniqueVisitorId = g.FirstOrDefault().UniqueVisitorId,` _as per my answer_, it works with your sample data.

Comment: Also @DylanLin a Map/Reduce should return a *specific* class. That class represents the *REDUCE* part of the index.. which is more or less a representation of your result. So when you say the class isn't elegant ... sorta makes no sense to me. It's a class that should represent *the result set schema* so it's not as if it's elegant or not. It's pragmatic AND it's accurate. Otherwise, change what results you are after and update the class accordingly.

Comment: I mean the use of UniqueVisitorId property is not elegant, because it's only a temp property, won't be used in the view.