# Raven DB: What's wrong with this multi-map/reduce index?

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

I have an application to track page visits for a website.
Here's my model:

```
public class VisitSession {
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public string UniqueVisitorId { get; set; }
    public IList<PageVisit> PageVisits { get; set; }
}
```

When a visitor go to the website, a visit session starts. One visit session has many page visits. The tracker will write a UniqueVisitorId (GUID) cookie when the first time a visitor go to the website. So we are able to know if a visitor is returning visitor.

Now I want to write a view displaying TotalVisitSessions, TotalPageVisits, TotalUniqueVisitors for each day. So I write this multi-map reduce:

```
public class VisitSummaryByDateIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<VisitSummaryByDate>
{
    public VisitSummaryByDateIndex()
    {
        AddMap<VisitSession>(sessions => from s in sessions
                                            select new VisitSummaryByDate
                                            {
                                                Date = s.StartTime.Date,
                                                TotalVisitSessions = 1,
                                                TotalPageVisits = 0,
                                                TotalNewVisitors = s.IsNewVisit ? 1 : 0,
                                                TotalUniqueVisitors = 0,
                                                UniqueVisitorId = s.UniqueVisitorId
                                            });

        AddMap<PageVisit>(visits => from v in visits
                                    select new VisitSummaryByDate
                                    {
                                        Date = v.VisitTime.Date,
                                        TotalVisitSessions = 0,
                                        TotalPageVisits = 1,
                                        TotalNewVisitors = 0,
                                        TotalUniqueVisitors = 0,
                                        UniqueVisitorId = String.Empty
                                    });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Date into g
                            select new VisitSummaryByDate
                            {
                                Date = g.Key,
                                TotalVisitSessions = g.Sum(it => it.TotalVisitSessions),
                                TotalPageVisits = g.Sum(it => it.TotalPageVisits),
                                TotalNewVisitors = g.Sum(it => it.TotalNewVisitors),
                                TotalUniqueVisitors = g.Select(it => it.UniqueVisitorId).Where(it => it.Length > 0).Distinct().Count(),
                                UniqueVisitorId = String.Empty
                            };
    }
}
```

The problem is in the "TotalUniqueVisitors" calculation, sometimes the TotalUniqueVisitors of the index result is 1, sometimes is 2. But I checked the data, it will never be like so less. Is there something wrong with my Map/Reduce syntax?

**Related post:** [Raven DB: How to create "UniqueVisitorCount by date" index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597359/raven-db-how-to-create-uniquevisitorcount-by-date-index)

**Code with sample data can be found here:** https://gist.github.com/2702071

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce is actually processed multiple time over the result.
Your index assume that this happens only once, and have access to the entire result set.

Your index need to looks like this:

```
public class VisitSummaryByDateIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<VisitSummaryByDate>
{
    public VisitSummaryByDateIndex()
    {
        AddMap<VisitSession>(sessions => from s in sessions
                                         select new VisitSummaryByDate
                                         {
                                             Date = s.StartTime.Date,
                                             TotalVisitSessions = 1,
                                             TotalPageVisits = 0,
                                             TotalNewVisitors = s.IsNewVisit ? 1 : 0,
                                             TotalUniqueVisitors = 1,
                                             UniqueVisitorId = new[]{s.UniqueVisitorId}
                                         });

        AddMap<PageVisit>(visits => from v in visits
                                    select new VisitSummaryByDate
                                    {
                                        Date = v.VisitTime.Date,
                                        TotalVisitSessions = 0,
                                        TotalPageVisits = 1,
                                        TotalNewVisitors = 0,
                                        TotalUniqueVisitors = 0,
                                        UniqueVisitorId = new string[0]
                                    });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Date into g
                            select new VisitSummaryByDate
                            {
                                Date = g.Key,
                                TotalVisitSessions = g.Sum(it => it.TotalVisitSessions),
                                TotalPageVisits = g.Sum(it => it.TotalPageVisits),
                                TotalNewVisitors = g.Sum(it => it.TotalNewVisitors),
                                TotalUniqueVisitors = g.Sum(it => it.TotalUniqueVisitors),,
                                UniqueVisitorId =  g.Select(x=>x.UniqueVisitorId).Distinct()
                             };
    }
}
```

Comment: (can't believe I'm questioning you!) but this doesn't work.  Each session is not necessarily a new unique id, so the sum isn't correct.  Also, I'm assuming UniqueVisitorId is supposed to be `IEnumerable<string>` now, so that doesn't compile.  However, looking at the post this question is based on (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597359/raven-db-how-to-create-uniquevisitorcount-by-date-index) I don't think that field is important anyway, hence my answer just setting it to FirstOrDefault.

Comment: You should actually remove `TotalUniqueVisitors` from here, and use `UniqueVisitorId.Count` to get the actual number of unique visitors.

Comment: @Simon Agree with you. But I think setting it to FirstOrDefault is not correct. Because reduce function will be process more than once (might take the output of itself as input). So if you use FirstOrDefault, you will sometimes get the result of 1 TotalUniqueVisits. I think I worked out the final solution according to Ayende's answer. But I am thinking about the performance now. Because the SelectMany in the reduce function makes the resulting documents very large. What do you guys think about it? Here's the new gist: https://gist.github.com/2702071

Comment: Thanks Ayende. What do you think about the performance problem? (see my above reply to Simon)

Comment: @DylanLin I wasn't able to recreate your issue of getting 1 TotalUniqueVisits - do you have a sample that recreates it? Re the perf question, I think that generally you want to return small documents from the index - so it really depends on how many unique ID's you think will be there.

Answer (score 2):

The correct index is:

```
public class VisitSummaryByDateIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<VisitSummaryByDate>
{
    public VisitSummaryByDateIndex()
    {
        AddMap<VisitSession>(sessions => from s in sessions
                                         select new VisitSummaryByDate
                                         {
                                             Date = s.StartTime.Date,
                                             TotalVisitSessions = 1,
                                             TotalPageVisits = 0,
                                             TotalNewVisitors = s.IsNewVisit ? 1 : 0,
                                             TotalUniqueVisitors = 0,
                                             UniqueVisitorId = s.UniqueVisitorId
                                         });

        AddMap<PageVisit>(visits => from v in visits
                                    select new VisitSummaryByDate
                                    {
                                        Date = v.VisitTime.Date,
                                        TotalVisitSessions = 0,
                                        TotalPageVisits = 1,
                                        TotalNewVisitors = 0,
                                        TotalUniqueVisitors = 0,
                                        UniqueVisitorId = string.Empty,
                                    });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Date into g
                            select new VisitSummaryByDate
                            {
                                Date = g.Key,
                                TotalVisitSessions = g.Sum(it => it.TotalVisitSessions),
                                TotalPageVisits = g.Sum(it => it.TotalPageVisits),
                                TotalNewVisitors = g.Sum(it => it.TotalNewVisitors),
                                TotalUniqueVisitors = g.Select(it => it.UniqueVisitorId).Where(x => x.Length > 0).Distinct().Count(),
                                UniqueVisitorId = g.FirstOrDefault().UniqueVisitorId,
                            };
    }
}
```

The difference is that UniqueVisitorId is set in the reduce.  I'm not 100% certain why this is needed yet, I must admit.

Comment: Ah, thanks to Ayende's answer we now know why it's required.  I'm not sure what benefit using an array like Ayende does gives you, but it also works using a string as per my answer.